# Calling 'wait' and 'notify' on this

Tags: java, multithreading

I have gone through pretty much every question on java multithreading here on SO, but I do not quite understand if my understanding is correct.

I wish to understand if the sequence of operations plays out as I have described below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Runner implements Runnable{
    long count = 0;
    JLabel label;
    boolean paused = false;

    public Runner(JLabel label){
        this.label = label;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                if(paused){
                    synchronized(this){
                        wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                count++;
                label.setText(Long.toString(count));
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    return;
        }
    }

    synchronized void pause_counting(){
        paused = true;
    }

    synchronized void start_counting(){
        paused = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

public class ThreadRace extends JApplet{
    boolean running = true;
    Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void init(){
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel threadProgress = new JLabel("0");
        final Runner runner = new Runner(threadProgress);
        thread = new Thread(runner);
        thread.start();

        panel.add(threadProgress);

        JButton toggle = new JButton("Stop");
        toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            synchronized public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Running: " + running);
                if(running){
                    runner.pause_counting();
                } else {
                    runner.start_counting();    
                }
                running = !running;
            }
        });
        panel.add(toggle);

        add(panel);
    }

    public void stop(){
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Is this how it works?

1. When I call the method `pause_counting()`, I am setting paused to false.
2. Inside of run(), I am taking hold of the lock to the object, `runner` inside of the `synchronized(this) { ... }` block.
3. When I make a call to `this.wait()`, I am releasing hold of the same lock which I just took possession of and go into the `WAITING` state.
4. At this point, any other method is free to do anything with `runner` (!)
5. I make a call to `start_counting()` eventually.
6. This makes the thread go back into the `RUNNING` state and continues from after the wait() statement. While it is still inside the `synchronized(this)` block, it gets hold of the lock
7. However, once it leaves the block, it releases the lock and execution continues

I am pretty sure there are a few flaws in my understanding.

Help? :(

Comment: Not an answer but related (and **highly recommended**): http://blog.smartbear.com/programming/why-johnny-cant-write-multithreaded-programs/

Comment: Your first error is synchronizing on different instances of `Runner`.

Comment: I understand that ideally, all three should be synchronized on the same monitor. However, I explicitly wish to understand the effect of using `this` instead. Perhaps this is not exactly the best example...

Comment: `this` is the lock, but since you are synchronizing on 3 different `this`'s, you don't achieve anything.

Comment: I wish to verify whether the sequence of operations plays out as I have described. The code itself is entirely nonsensical from the point of actually needing multiple locks, I concede as much.

Comment: Updated to involve a single counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this how it works?

Yes.  All of your statements are true with some tweaks (see below).

However, there is are bugs in your program.  Because the thread is testing for `paused` while *not* inside of a `synchronized` block, you need to make sure that `paused` is `volatile` to provide memory synchronization.

```
volatile boolean paused = false
```

This is probably also necessary with the `JLabel` array as well.  Any time you have a threads that are changing shared variables, there needs to be memory synchronization.

---

> When I call the method pause_counting(), I am setting paused to false.

Yes.  Updating `paused` here is ok because it is in a `synchronized` method.

> Inside of run(), I am taking hold of the lock to an object, runner[i] inside of the synchronized(this) { ... } block.

Only if `paused` is true.  Since you are testing for `paused` outside of the `synchronized` block, `paused` needs to be `volatile` to ensure memory synchronization between threads.

> When I make a call to this.wait(), I am releasing hold of the same lock which I just took possession of and go into the WAITING state.

Right.

> At this point, any other method is free to do anything with this runner[i] (!)

Well it was free to do stuff before but now that the lock is released it can call `synchronized` methods without blocking.

> I make a call to start_counting() eventually.

Right.  This calls `notifyAll()`.

> This makes the thread go back into the RUNNING state and continues from after the wait() statement. While it is still inside the synchronized(this) block, it gets hold of the lock

Well first it makes the thread go into the `BLOCKED` state until the caller of `start_counting()` leaves that method and releases the lock.

> However, once it leaves the block, it releases the lock and execution continues

Right.

Comment: Thank you. :)

Including the check for `paused` inside of the `synchronized(this) { ... }` block will achieve the same objective, right?

Comment: Yes that will work @SohamPal.  You should update the `JLabel` in a `synchronized` block as well or make it a `volatile` field on the `Runner` as well.